# error showing incompatible data types where read() gets a character datatype and variable is also a character data type

Tags: java

> error: incompatible types: possible lossy conversion from int to char.

I tried to declare n as integer datatype, then instead of getting a character as output I was getting a number.

```
import java.io.*;
 class test
 {
  public static void main(String arg[]) throws IOException
  {
   char n;
   DataInputStream input=new DataInputStream(System.in);
   System.out.print("Enter a character:");
   n=input.read();
   System.out.print(n);
   }
  }`
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I got Like this

DataInputStream.read returns an ascii value of input type cast it to char

```
n=(char)input.read();
```

Comment: Input.read returns the number of bytes readed. Not the char itself

Comment: I accept with you jens when the input is file, But when it is keyboard input, System.in read bytes and converts it into the required form, when readLine method is called on that DataInputStream instance it Converts it to String.

Comment: Thank  you Karthik. It worked and I got the output but I don't get why read() method  returns ascii value of a character, when its function is to return a character.

Comment: Priyanka, You must have been aware that Java allocates two bytes of memory to character because it is stored in unicode format. When you are using DataInputStream it reads byte by byte in ascii format which is one byte representation of your character. That is the reason when you are using readChar() function you must be getting some spanish or some other language character.

Answer (score 0):

That is because [read()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FilterInputStream.html#read()) method gives you an integer. Actually you want to use     [readChar()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataInputStream.html#readChar())

```
n=input.readChar();
```